# Can't install python-qt4 or python-twisted on Lubuntu

Tags: apt, lubuntu, python3

I am trying to install Armory Bitcoin Wallet on Lubuntu. It comes in a .deb. The install fails with error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of armory:
 armory depends on python-qt4; however:
  Package python-qt4 is not installed.
 armory depends on python-twisted; however:
  Package python-twisted is not installed.
```

When I try to install `python-qt4` or `python-twisted` I get errors like:

```
E: Package 'python-qt4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-twisted' has no installation candidate
```

I have searched for info on the right sources to use with Lubuntu for these installs but no success. Can anyone point me in the direction of the right repositories to add? or is it a different problem?

The OS vrsion is Lubuntu 20.04.

The links to the armory download are below, but the errors relating to `python-qt4` and `python-twisted` are reproducible without reference to the Armory stuff.

For info the armory details are: I tried both of these [armory_0.96-gcc5.4_amd64.deb](https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory/releases/download/v0.96/armory_0.96-gcc5.4_amd64.deb) and [armory_0.96-gcc4.7_amd64.deb](https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory/releases/download/v0.96/armory_0.96-gcc4.7_amd64.deb) from [bitcoinarmory.com](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/download/). They both fail with the same error.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? From where have you downloaded the *Armory Bitcoin Wallet*?

Comment: @N0rbert I have added these details as requested. Note: The error is nothing to do with the Armory install. The commands ```sudo apt install python-qt4``` and ```sudo apt install python-twisted``` also fail with error messages as given above when done independently   of the dpkg command.

Comment: The mentioned Qt4 and twisted packages do not exist in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository. So you can not install this software directly on 20.04 LTS. Use 18.04 LTS instead.

Comment: @N0rbert, Thanks. You say "not directly", can it be done indirectly? I am fairly sure I managed to do it a few days ago on a previous attempt. Could I have accidentally hit on the indirect way that you hint at?

Comment: Possible indirect methods - use Docker container for this application, schroot or maybe full VirtualMachine. But last method is overkill. Reinstalling still supported 18.04 LTS is better.